# OpenGL - How can I move my printed lines?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I have set up a mouse function which is called in my main() like so:

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::vector <point> points;
point OnePoint;

void processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

    if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        int yy;
        yy = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        y = yy - y; /* In Glut, Y coordinate increases from top to bottom */
        OnePoint.x = x;
        OnePoint.y = y;
        points.push_back(OnePoint);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

and to print a line through the vertices I have written some code in my display function that allows me to do just that:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

for (int i = 0; i < points.size();i++)
{
    glVertex2i(points[i].x, points[i].y);
}

glEnd();
```

However now what I want to do is move all the lines either left or right when I click the correct arrow keys to do so, but I can't figure out how.

I'm aware that it could possibly be something like:

`glVertex2i(points[i].x + 10, points[i].y);` // moving points 10 along the x axis

However since `i` is out of the `for loop`, I get error messages

Comment: "However since i is out of the for loop, I get error messages" what do you mean out of the loop and what error you  get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should introduce a new variable:

```
std::vector <point> points;
point offset; // <- how much to offset points
```

Make sure to set it to zero during initialization.

Then in the drawing code you add that offset to each point:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
for (int i = 0; i < points.size();i++)
    glVertex2i(points[i].x + offset.x, points[i].y + offset.y);
glEnd();
```

Or use a translation matrix to do that automagically:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(offset.x, offset.y, 0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
for (int i = 0; i < points.size();i++)
    glVertex2i(points[i].x, points[i].y);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

On the key-press handler you just change the `offset`:

```
// left-arrow:
offset.x -= 1;

// right-arrow:
offset.x += 1;

...
```

Comment: You are a star. I really should have thought about this, it makes sense to just make a new vector and increment it. I was trying to just increment by a normal value which is where I got errors. Thanks!